# Recoding variables to combine two questions in SPSS

Tags: spss

In my questionnaire,I asked these two questions:

1. q1. Have you ever been on a holiday that included a visit to a film
   location?

   - Yes (Go to  next Question)
   - No
2. q2. Have you ever been to a film location with the prime reason being to visit that film site?

   - Yes
   - No.

In terms of people answers to these questions, I divided them into 3 groups. first those who said no to q1, second those who said yes to q2 and third those who said no to q2.
my problem is that, I must use ANOVA analysis, because I have 3 groups. But I don't know how can I merge answers of these two questions in one variable in SPSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way it's to take the variable which represents q2. Recode the values like this:

- emptycase = 1
- yes = 2
- no = 3

If you don't know how to recode, look at [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Using_SPSS_and_PASW/Recoding_Variables).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think I coulden't explain my problem well. Actually I want to put those who answered no to q1, and those who answered to q2 (yes and no) in one new variable. I want to know is it possible or not?

Comment: yes, I understand. If you want to preserve the original variable just copy the original one. Then recode the copy as I said